# S7FTPRequest to local wifi network IP Address problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I am FTPing a file using S7FTPRequest with no problems in the iOS simulator to a FTP Server running on my Fusion VM Windows 7 machine.

When I install the app on my iPad and try to do the same exact thing nothing happens, he FTP server does not even log that a request came in.  Could it be a setting in my router?  My ipad is connected to the network via WiFi - shouldn't it be able to talk to the FTP Server?

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem of setting in router. Using WiFi definitely you can talk to the FTP Server.

Comment: S7FTPRequest is now called SCRFTPRequest and located here https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest